# What is the impact of doubling a sample size on a p-value

Tags: p-value, least-squares, statistical-power

Assuming that their is an underlying relationship between two variables in an OLS regression [null hypothesis testing], then what is the impact on the p-value of doubling the sample size? (assuming that the initial sample is representative of the population, and the subsequent sample is also representative).

Obviously i'm aware that so long as there is an underlying relationship, then increasing the sample size should reduce the p-value, but I'm interested in understanding further the nature of the relationship between p and n.

Comment: I assume you're thinking about the $p$ value associated with the $t$ that is calculated for each regression coefficient. I don't have the answer, but if you want to explore this issue for yourself you will want to consider that sample size acts on that $p$ value in two ways. Firstly, increased N means a decreased standard error and consequently a higher $t$. Secondly, for a given $t$, increasing N will increase df (occassionally termed $v$ in the $t$-distribution), which in term will increase the $p$ value associated with that $t$.

Comment: @Ian_Fin, Increasing the degrees of freedom with _decrease_ the p-value, all else held equal.

Comment: @not_bonferroni Good spot! I must have been thinking in terms of things getting "increasingly significant" and typed the wrong word.

Comment: Increasing the sample size will tend to *increase* the p-value when the null hypothesis is true and *decrease* it when the null is false.  These are merely *tendencies,* though, because p-values are random.  In particular, there are two sharply different ways to read this question: one concerns behaviors of p-values *a priori* and the other concerns *predicting* changes in p-values *after performing a regression on a particular data set*: in other words, *conditional* on a given p-value.  Which interpretation is the intended one?

Comment: @whuber: why would you expect the p-values to increase when the null is true? Say, when all the classical assumptions are met, p-values constructed from the t-distribution would lead me to expect standard uniform p-values for any $n$?

Comment: @Christoph I apologies for not being fully rigorous in that statement.  When the null is a simple hypothesis and the test statistic has a continuous distribution and the null is true, then the p-value will have a uniform distribution.  Half the time, then, the *original* p-value will be less than $0.5$.  It will be more likely than not that the p-value will *increase* with more data.  The other half of the time the original p-value will be greater than $0.5$ and, more likely than not, will *decrease* with more data.

Answer (score 6):

For the T test we have rules like "Doubling the sample size increases the test statistic by $\sqrt{2}$ ". This might make you think that there is a simple relationship between sample size and p-value.

In fact the relationship between sample size and p-value depends on the relationship between sample size and the test statistic, and the relationship between test statistic and p-value. Those relationships will be different for every test.

For the most simple case, the one sided Z test, we can see what this relationship is. Suppose a random variable $X$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Uppose that we are testing if the mean of $X$ is significantly different from $\nu$. The test statistic $Z$ is $\frac{(\bar{x}-\nu)\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}$.

The p value is equal to one minus the CDF of the $Z$ statistic (this assumes that the difference between means is positive, a similar argument works if the difference is negative).

For the normal distribution the CDF is $\Phi(t)=0.5+0.5\cdot erf(\frac{x-\mu_t}{\sigma_t \sqrt{2}})$. Where erf(x) is the error function.

Under the null hypothesis of equal means the $Z$ statistic has a mean $0$ and variance $1$. The actual distribution of $Z$ has a mean of $\frac{(\bar{x}-\nu)\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}$ and variance $1$.

The effect size of the difference between the means is $\frac{(\bar{x}-\nu)}{\sigma}$. Call the effect size $b$, then the expected value of $Z$ is $b\sqrt{n}$.

For $Z$ the CDF is $\Phi(z)=0.5+0.5\cdot erf(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}})$. Where erf(x) is the error function.

Of course the $Z$ statistic is a random variable, here we'll just look at the relationship between sample size and p-value for the expected value of $Z$.

It follows that the CDF of the $Z$ statistic is $\Phi(z)=0.5+0.5\cdot erf(\frac{b\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2}})$

This is the relationship between the p value and sample size

$p=0.5-0.5\cdot erf(\frac{b\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2}})$

The relationship varies according to the value of $n$. For very large $n$ we can use a series expansion to see the limiting behavior. According to wolfram alpha that is:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}p = e^{-0.5b^2n} \left(\frac{1}{eb\sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{(b\sqrt{n})^2} \right) \right)$

That is quite a quick decay towards 0. There is a big dependence on the effect size, of course if the difference between means is greater then the p value will shrink more quickly as your sampling improves.

Again, remember that this is only for the Z and T test, it doesn't apply to other tests.

Comment: Basic principles inform us that (1) p-values are *random quantities*; (2) they do depend on sample size; but (3) they also depend on the actual state of nature--that is, not only on whether the null hypothesis true or false, but on what specific distribution governs the results.  Because your answer does not appear to recognize either (1) or (3), it's difficult to determine how informative or reliable its information is.

Comment: @whuber I admit that my notation is bad so its a bit unclear. I mention (3), the state of nature is the effect size of the difference between population means. You're right about (1), I didn't treat the p-value like a random variable, I was searching for a rule of thumb like "Doubling the sample size leads to the T statistic increasing by $\sqrt{2}$". I was looking at the effect of sample size on the expected p-value. Good thing you pointed it out so I can clarify this for future readers.

Comment: @Hugh the OP's question concerned tests of parameters from OLS models, which is directly connected to Z or T tests when considering Wald based tests. However, can you say whether the standard errors of regression coefficients are directly proportional to a factor of $1/\sqrt{n}$ as with other Z or T tests?

Answer (score 5):

Let us first investigate the effect on the *t-value*. We can then immediately infer the effect on p-value.

This is perhaps best illustrated by a well-chosen simulation example which illustrates the most salient features. Since we're looking at $H_0$ being false (and we're essentially considering properties related to power) it makes sense to focus on a one-tailed test (in the "correct" direction) since looking at the wrong tail won't see much action and won't tell us much of interest.

So here we have a situation (at n=100) where the effect is large enough that the statistic is sometimes significant. We then add to that first sample a second drawing from the same continuous distribution of x-values (here uniform but it's not critical to the observed effect) of the same size as the first, leading to a doubling of the sample size, but entirely including the first sample.

[image: Plot of t-value for slope with initial sample vs larger sample]

What we observe is *not* that the p-value goes down, only that it tends to go down (more points lie above the diagonal line than below it); we can see that the variation in t-values reduces, so there are fewer in the region of 0. Many p-values go up. Quite a number of samples that were insignificant became significant when we added more data, but some that were significant became insignificant.

[Here we're looking at the t-statistic for the slope coefficient in a simple regression, though qualitatively the issues are similar more broadly.]

A plot of p-values instead of t-values conveys essentially the same information. Indeed if you put tick-markings at the right intervals on the axes above, you could label them with p-values instead ... but the top (and right) would show low p-values and the bottom (/left) would be labelled with larger p-values. [Actually plotting the p-values just squashes everything up into the corner, and it's less clear what's going on.]

Answer (score 3):

In general, when the respective null is false, expect decay of the p-values as in the figure below, where I report average p-values from little simulation study for multiples of samples of size `n=25` ranging from `bb*n=25`to `bb*n=29*25` for a simple linear regression coefficient equal to 0.1 and error standard deviation of $\sigma_u=0.5$.

Since the p-values are bounded from below by zero, the decay must ultimately flatten out.

The 90% confidence interval (shaded blue area) indicates that, moreover, the variability of the p-values also decreases with sample size.

[image]

Evidently, when either $\sigma_u$ is smaller or $n$ larger, the p-values will be close to zero faster when increasing `bb`, so that the appearance of the plot will be flatter.

Code:

```r
    reps <- 5000
    B <- seq(1,30,by=2)
    n <- 25
    
    sigma.u <- .5
    pvalues <- matrix(NA,reps,length(B))
    for (bb in 1:length(B)){
         for (i in 1:reps){
              x <- rnorm(B[bb]*n)
              y <- .1*x + rnorm(B[bb]*n,sd=sigma.u)
              pvalues[i,bb] <- summary(lm(y~x))$coefficients[2,4]     
         }
    }
    plot(B,colMeans(pvalues),type="l", lwd=2, col="purple",  
            ylim=c(0,.9))
    ConfidenceInterval <- apply(pvalues, 2, quantile, 
                                 probs = c(.1,.9))
    x.ax <- c(B,rev(B))
    y.ax <- c(ConfidenceInterval[1,], 
                 rev(ConfidenceInterval[2,]))
    polygon(x.ax,y.ax, col=alpha("blue", alpha = .2), border=NA)
```

Comment: Because a p-value is a random quantity, it is important to explain that the vertical axis in your plot displays your estimates of *expected* p-values rather than p-values themselves.  In light of this, showing the *variation* among p-values for any given $B$ would be an essential adjunct to your analysis.

Comment: @whuber, that is what I tried to emphasize by writing "expect", but it is, hopefully, a little more explicit like this now.

Comment: +1 but the "flattening out" would presumably disappear if you were to plot `log(p)` instead of `p` itself.

Comment: @amoeba: yes, running the same script for log-pvalues appears to produce a straight line.

Comment: +1 Plots of expected p-values are a very powerful way to display issues and effects related to power. A fuller display and discussion of them (with references) is in section 2.5 of my open access chapter "A reckless guide to p-values" here https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286#Sec3